# Copy and Insert rows from one sheet to another by pushing a macro button

Tags: excel, vba

I have this workbook:
I need to have a macro button that my users can click that say "Click Here to Copy", then i need a code that copies rows number 5-25 of sheet titled "TC-Star Here", and i need the copied rows to be inserted (i need the pasted rows to not auto delete the ones that were there previously, so the inserted rows would have to shift the previous ones down) into another sheet named "Time Cards". The inserted rows, i need to have to code insert them starting at cell A1. So everytime the macro button is clicked, rows are copied, and inserted with the previous data unmodified/deleted.

I have this code so far:

```
Sub CopyInfo()
On Error GoTo Err_Execute
    Sheet2.Range("A1:F11").Value = Sheet1.Range("A1:F11").Value
    Sheet1.Range("A1:F11").Copy
    Sheet2.Range("A1").InsertCopiedCells
Err_Execute:
    MsgBox "All have been copied!"

End Sub
```

But everytime the button is clicked, it pastes the rows over the existing rows.

Please Help.

Comment: Oh, and you might want to ditch your `On Error GoTo`, at least temporarily. It may be suppressing error messages that would be helpful in diagnosing the problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is this what you are trying?

```
Sub CopyInfo()
    On Error GoTo Err_Execute

    Sheet1.Range("A1:F11").Copy
    Sheet2.Range("A1").Rows("1:1").Insert Shift:=xlDown

Err_Execute:
    If Err.Number = 0 Then MsgBox "All have been copied!" Else _
    MsgBox Err.Description
End Sub
```

Comment: I tried this code, It seems to  do what i need it to, but I need it to do a loop and continues to copy starting at the top and shifting down. Right now, it only copies to the first row, then everytime i click the macro, it keeps coping over the same area.

Comment: So what would be lovely is if the code could somehow identify the first blank row from the top, and every time, inserts the copied selection which shifting the entire document down.

Comment: Hmm, I missed these messages. The above code copies Range("A1:F11") and not just the 1st row...

Answer (score 1):

This line

`Sheet2.Range("A1:F11").Value = Sheet1.Range("A1:F11").Value`

is setting the value of those cells on Sheet2 to the values on Sheet1 - that is, it's copying the values over and replacing what was there. THEN, you're doing your copy-insert operation.

Delete/comment out that line and see what happens.

Also, I believe the copy area and the paste area have to be the same size. Try making it `Sheet2.Range("A1:F11").InsertCopiedCells`

Comment: Ok. I think the copy area and the paste area have to be the same size. Try making it `Sheet2.Range("A1:F11").InsertCopiedCells`

Comment: I have tried everything. I've tried doing that, and it does not work. So i've started with this new code:Sub CopyInfo()
On Error GoTo Err_Execute
        Sheets("Sheet1").Select
        Range("A1:F11").Select
        Selection.Copy
        Sheets("Sheet2").Select
        Selection.Insert
Err_Execute:
        MsgBox "The Data has been successfully Copied"
    
End Sub
ALL I REALLY NEED is a code that copies rows from one sheet and inserts them into another sheet without my data being replaced.Can someone please help me. I'm beyond frustrated.

Answer (score 1):

Simple - Use a loop (Also, turn off ScreenUpdating to greatly speed up the processing time)
The following will copy all rows from the sheet named "Sheet2" over to the same row in sheet named "Sheet1"

```
Sub CopyOver()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For j = 1 To 1560 'Or however many rows u have
        On Error GoTo Err_Execute
        Sheets("Sheet2").Rows(j).Copy
        Sheets("Sheet1").Rows(j).Insert Shift:=xlDown
    Next j
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Err_Execute:
        If Err.Number = 0 Then MsgBox "All have been copied!" Else _
        MsgBox Err.Description
End Sub
```

Answer (score -1):

Thx for the post dude~, each answer provider solve my problem~.
Here are my coding use in excel, for each selection will insert to Sheet 2,

```
  Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()

      Selection.Copy
      Sheet2.Range("A4").Rows("1:1").Insert Shift:=xlDown
      Sheets("Sheet1").Select
      Application.CutCopyMode = False
      Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp

  End Sub
```

Answer (score -1):

```
Sub Test()
    With ActiveSheet
    lastrow = .Cells(.rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    lastrow = lastrow - 1
    MsgBox lastrow
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: **From review queue:** May I request you to please add some more context around your answer. Code-only answers are difficult to understand. It will help the asker and future readers both if you can add more information in your post.